# Symfony4 - Error: "Notice: Undefined index: dbname" in AbstractOracleDriver.php while trying to create database

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, oci8

I am using Symfony 4.0.3 and I need connect to Oracle DB. I follow this instructions:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

my .env file

```
DATABASE_URL=oci8://user:pwd@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/something
```

host address is from tnsnames.ora -> HOST, something is from tnsnames.ora -> SERVICE_NAME

And after running command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\myapp>
2018-01-25T12:58:47+00:00 [error] Error thrown while running command 
"doctrine:d
atabase:create". Message: "Notice: Undefined index: dbname"

In AbstractOracleDriver.php line 125:

  Notice: Undefined index: dbname
```

I am able to connect to DB by plain PHP, but through Symfony not. dbname is something from my connect url at .env file. This is set from tnsnames.ora.

Comment: Can you add your `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` to the question, please?
 You can debug doctrine's current configuration by running `bin/console debug:container --parameters` and inspecting the `doctrine.*` parameters.

Comment: This file was not changed. I was following that instructions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `dbname` parameter is not picked up from your environment variable / DBAL url.

To solve this quickly just use **explicit configuration** instead of URL for doctrine DBAL's configuration.

The full reference configuration can be found in the symfony documentation -
 [Doctrine DBAL Reference Configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#reference-dbal-configuratio)

The documentation for the Doctrine DBAL Oracle configuration can be found [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#pdo-oci-oci8).

`config/packages/doctrine.yaml`:

```
doctrine:
  # [..]
  dbal:
    default_connection:   oracle_db_1
    connections:
      oracle_db_1:
        driver:    'oci8' # ... or 'pdo_oci'
        dbname:    '<dbname>'
        host:      '<host>'
        port:      '<port>'
        user:      '<user>'
        password:  '<password>'
```

If that works replace dbname, host, port etc. with container parameters (i.e. `'%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'`) read from environment variables  and add those to your .env file.

Answer (score 0):

doctrine.yaml edited like this:

```
parameters:
# Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
# This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
# environment variables are not available yet.
# You should not need to change this value.
#env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
      default_connection:   default
      connections:
        default:
          driver:    'oci8' # ... or 'pdo_oci'
          dbname:    'dbname'
          host:      'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
          port:      '1521'
          user:      'user'
          password:  'pwd'

# With Symfony 3.3, remove the `resolve:` prefix
#         url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%' 
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

after command 
    php bin/console doctrine:database:create

I have same error.

```
2018-01-26T06:23:31+00:00 [error] Error thrown while running command            "doctrine:d
atabase:create". Message: "Notice: Undefined index: dbname"

In AbstractOracleDriver.php line 125:

  Notice: Undefined index: dbname
```

my dbname is same as I have in SQL Developer in SID item.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in doctrine/dbal version <= 2.8.0.
Upgrade to doctrine/dbal to version 2.9.0 and it should start to work.

Here is the github pull request solving this issue: 
https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/3297

Answer (score 0):

If you use the *SERVICE_NAME* for your connection, you can define the *DATABASE_URL* like this:

```
    DATABASE_URL=oci8://user:pw@x.x.x.x:1521/?service=1&servicename=something&charset=AL32UTF8
```